# Help with unlocking user account

Tags: root

I added my username to the root group. Now when I try to log into the gui the screen flashes and goes back to the login. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you change the title into "Cannot login" or something, since your account isn't locked ?

Comment: I tried to set the title to "Cannot login after adding user to group root" and a couple other things but the forum post page kept throwing me error saying I needed to change the title.